# Liferay service builder 5.2

Tags: liferay

Can any body please suggest me some reference material from where I can study about Liferay Service Builder 5.2.

Answer (score 1):

I remember that the most helpful thing to do was studying the [DTD definition of service.xml](http://svn.liferay.com/browse/portal/trunk/definitions/liferay-service-builder_5_2_0.dtd?r=HEAD)

Service.xml is metadata definition for service builder and the DTD is very well documented.

Otherwise you can checkout the sample [service builder plugin](http://svn.liferay.com/repos/public/plugins/trunk/portlets/sample-service-builder-portlet/) and play with it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this ...

http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Extend+Liferay+Tables

Answer (score 0):

- Liferay in Action: http://serwis.kampus.uj.edu.pl/cds/books/Liferay.in.Action.pdf
- Liferay Cookbook: https://de.scribd.com/document/258113207/Life-Ray-Cookbook